# How to do horizontal scroll bar in mobile view with this code

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to horizontal scrollbar in mobile view with this code can anyone suggest how to do..

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs  nav-justified" id="menutabs" style="width: 100%;">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_0">
      <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:1rem;">star</i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_1">Master</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_2">Transaction</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_3">Reports</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_4">Analysis</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_6">Setup</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is HTML code, not JS.

Comment: ok can you tell me how to do?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you can use overflow-x to add a scrollbar. You can then use `overflow-x`, and you can set it to

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

or

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

Auto sets it up so it only adds a scrollbar if the site needs it, and scroll adds it all the time.

For example:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: scroll; /* or use auto*/
}
```

```html
<li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_0">
                <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:1rem;">star</i>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_1">Master</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_2">Transaction</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_3">Reports</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_4">Analysis</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_6">Setup</a>
                    </li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnOpb.png  open image  I want to horizontal scrollbar in header

Comment: You didn't include that code or anything, how can you expect me to do this before you tell me to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Set overflow-x to scroll, like: `overflow-x:scroll;`

Answer (score 0):

[this is the image view of scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w2s5.png)

The flex-wrap property specifies the flexible items should wrap and not goes to next line and overflow x do it horizontal scroll on mobile version. and webkit-scrollbar for beautify the scroll on mobile version. its only work on mobile view.

```css
@media  (max-width: 767px) {
ul#menutabs {
    display: flex !important;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
ul#menutabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 2px !important;
    /* margin-top: 33px; */
}

ul#menutabs::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #78909c;
}

ul#menutabs::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:#3333334f;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <linK href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">    
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs  nav-justified" id="menutabs" style="width: 100%;">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_0">
      <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:1rem;">star</i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_1">Master</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_2">Transaction</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_3">Reports</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_4">Analysis</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_6">Setup</a>
  </li>
</ul>




    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Add this on mobile view its give you horizontal scroll. for beautify scroll you can add the webkit-scrollbar style**

```
@media  (max-width: 767px) {
    ul#menutabs {
            display: flex !important;
            overflow-x: scroll;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            align-items: center;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
        }
        ul#menutabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 5px;
            height: 2px !important;
         }
        ul#menutabs::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: #78909c;
         }
        ul#menutabs::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background-color:#3333334f;
         }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this will only work in mobile view please check on mobile view only

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use **overflow-x** to add a scrollbar.
set it to,

`overflow-x: scroll;`

or

`overflow-x: auto;`

Auto sets it up so it only adds a scrollbar if the site needs it, and scroll adds it all the time.

For example:

`body { overflow-x: scroll; /* or use auto*/ }`